# accumulating a value in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to accumulate a value when a certain condition exists such as

`If statusCode = 0
then add 1 to a value.`

I am trying to show the number of successful records as defined by the statusCode.

There must be a better way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result. How does your current query attempt look?

Comment: It seems a Select count(*) From _yourtable_ Where _yourcondition_

Comment: My DBMS is Sybase Anywhere. It is embedded in an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select count(1) from yourTable where statusCode=0
```

Comment: I can't believe I could not pull that out of my head. Thanks I think that will work.

Comment: How do I then assign this to a column such as - AS "Succes Number"